# If current menu item is child or parent with child?

Tags: menus, sub-menu

Is it possible to check in WP if the current page/menu item is a child or a parent with child (in my wp_nav_menu)? So not if the page has a child page, but if the menu item is a parent with child or a child (based on my wp_nav_menu).

Comment: It is a bit unclear what you are trying to achieve. You should specify you question and add relevant information.

Comment: Well, when Im on a page, i want to check whether the page is a child or a parent (with a child), based on the defined wp_nav_menu in WP admin. Hope that is clear.

Comment: You know about the [nav menu css classes](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu#Menu_Item_CSS_Classes)? Otherwise you likely have to deal with [Walker_Nav_Menu](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/Walker_Nav_Menu) in one or another way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with ialocin, if you can use the [built-in nav menu css classes](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu#Menu_Item_CSS_Classes) you should but if those aren't enough there's a nice little filter which can help with css classes. If you need something other than CSS classes you can use a [Custom Walker](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/Walker) ( as ialocin suggested ) and use the same logic as the function below.

**Add some CSS Classes to WP Nav Menu**

```
/** Custom `wp_nav_menu()` Classes **/
function add_class_to_wp_nav_menu( $classes, $item ) {

    if( hasChildren( $item->object_id ) ) {                     // hasChildren is a Custom Function
        array_push( $classes, 'has-children' );
    }

    if( 0 !== wp_get_post_parent_id( $item->object_id ) ) {     // 0 means there is no parent
        array_push( $classes, 'has-parent' );
    }

    return $classes;
}
add_filter( 'nav_menu_css_class', 'add_class_to_wp_nav_menu', 10, 2 );

/** Check if Page has Children **/
function has_children( $pid ) {
    $children = get_pages( "child_of={$pid}" );
    return ( $children );
}
```

Comment: Correct answer, I guess - but isn't this just duplicating existing classes, e.g. `menu-item-has-children` or `current-menu-parent`? So you could just use them. @RobbertT

Comment: @ialocin ha, yeah I guess you're right. Default classes are pretty informative.